# changing the font weight after editing is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table which is editable. Then I have two buttons which are used to change the padding of the td content.

My requirement is

1. When the td content padding reaches 20px the content font weight should be bold. When it reach 40px(on the second click) font-style should be normal and when it reaches 60px(third click) the font color should be gray.
2. It was working well before editing, but after it does not work.

```js
 $(function () {
                $("td.cat").dblclick(function () {
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
                    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
                    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                })
            })
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("tr").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected1');
                });
            });

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                $(".cat").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });

                $("#key").click(function () {

                    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
                    sl = sl >= 100 ? "100" : "+=20";

                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": sl

                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("cellEditing2"));
                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;

                        var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;

                        if (isPaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
                        else if (isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
                        else $(this).css("color", "grey");
                    });
                });
                $("#key1").click(function () {
                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": "-=" + "20"
                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var PaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;
                        var PaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;
                        if (PaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
                        else if (isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "normal");
                        else $(this).css("color", "grey");
                    });
                });

            });
```

```css
      .selected {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

       .editableTable {
    position:static;
      width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse;
        
       
} 
.editableTable td { 
     border: 1px solid;
   
   height:17px;

        .editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .editableTable .cellEditing1 {
            padding: 0;
            height: 1px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>


    <table class="editableTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="cat">rose</td>
            <td class="cat">red</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cat">cash</td>
            <td class="cat">black</td>
           
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onKeyPress=checkFunction()` will be helpful. use this in the `<input></input>`

```
 $(function () {
                $("td.cat").dblclick(function () {
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
                    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
                    $(this).html("<input id='value' onKeyPress="checkFunction()" type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                })
            })
// rest of your code goes here...
```

In the checkFunction(), write your actual logic!

```
function checkFunction(){
  var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("cellEditing2"));
  var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
  var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;
  var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;
  if (isPaddingLeft20)
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
  else if (isPaddingLeft40) 
    $(this).css("font-style", "italic"); 
  else 
    $(this).css("color", "grey");
}
```

Comment: @ G surendar thina its not working in my code can you please add the complete code with output

Comment: try changing it in the `<input>` tag

Comment: which is your function that checks your logic??

Comment: $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("cellEditing2"));
                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;

                        var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;

                        if (isPaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
                        else if (isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
                      else $(this).css("color", "grey");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116429/discussion-between-g-surendar-thina-and-manu-p).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Sample Array in chunkSize</title>
<style> .selected {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }

       .editableTable {
    position:static;
      width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse;


} 
.editableTable td { 
     border: 1px solid;

   height:17px;

        .editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text] {
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .editableTable .cellEditing1 {
            padding: 0;
            height: 1px;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>


    <table class="editableTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="cat">rose</td>
            <td class="cat">red</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cat">cash</td>
            <td class="cat">black</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(function () {
                $("td.cat").dblclick(function () {
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
                    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
                    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                })

                $("tr").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected1');
                });


                $(".cat").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });

                $("#key").click(function () {

                    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
                    sl = sl >= 100 ? "100" : "+=20";

                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": sl

                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                        var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var isPaddingLeft20="",isPaddingLeft40='';
                        if(paddingLeftpl>20)
                         isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeftpl;
                        if(paddingLeftpl>40)
                            isPaddingLeft40=paddingLeftpl;
                        if (isPaddingLeft20){ $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");$(this).find('input').css("font-weight", "bold");$(this).css("color", "green")}
                         if (isPaddingLeft40){  $(this).find('input').css("font-style", "italic");$(this).css("font-style", "italic");$(this).css("color", "blue");$(this).find('input').css("color", "blue");}
                        else $(this).css("color", "grey");
                    });
                });
                $("#key1").click(function () {
                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": "-=" + "20"
                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                       var paddingLeftpl = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var isPaddingLeft20="",isPaddingLeft40='';
                        if(paddingLeftpl<22)
                         isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeftpl;
                        if(paddingLeftpl<42)
                            isPaddingLeft40=paddingLeftpl;
                        if (isPaddingLeft20){ $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");$(this).find('input').css("font-weight", "normal");$(this).css("color", "black")}
                         if (isPaddingLeft40){  $(this).find('input').css("font-style", "normal");$(this).css("font-style", "normal");$(this).css("color", "brown");$(this).find('input').css("color", "brown");}
                        else $(this).css("color", "grey");
                    });

            });

            });


            </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the colors accordingly

Comment: can you explain  this line 
  var isPaddingLeft20="",isPaddingLeft40='';

Comment: initalizing variables to ''